# Select pivot data in self referencing table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table say for example is full of places. For example:

```
ID  Name          ParentId
--------------------------
1   UK            NULL
2   England       1
3   Bedfordshire  2
4   Bedford       3
5   ShopA         4   
6   Hertfordshire 2
7   Stevenage     6
8   ShopB         7
9   ShopsX        6
```

I want to run a query that will bring back the data as a hierachy

```
UK | England | Bedfordshire | Bedford   | ShopA
UK | England | Herfordshire | Stevenage | ShopB
UK | England | Herfordshire | ShopsX    | NULL
```

Note the last row, I don't want to call it as follows:

```
NULL | UK | England | Herfordshire | ShopsX
```

Using a query like this:

```
 SELECT c.name as cname, b.name as bname, a.name as aname
  FROM table a 
 left JOIN table b
  ON b.Id = a.Parentid
 left join table c
  ON c.Id = b.Parentid
```

I am getting results where the first values NULL.

Like

```
NULL | UK | England | Herfordshire | ShopsX
```

IS it possible to switch the query round so the NULLs align to the right somehow?

Comment: That's not a hierarchy. That's more like pivoting than anything else. If you knew that the number of levels is fixed and you used hierarchyid instead of self-referencing, you could use the level number to PIVOT, or write an equivalent exception. HierarchyID is required to make level calculation cheap

Comment: Oh maybe that's what I need. Is what I have done correct for a hierarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your hierarchy has a fixed number of levels, you can use as many self-joins as there are levels to retrieve one row per shop:

```
select country.name,region.name,county.name,town.name,shop.name
from shops country
   inner join shops region on region.ParentID=country.id
   inner join shops county on county.ParentID=region.id
   inner join shops town on town.ParentID=county.id
   inner join shops shop on shop.parentid=town.id
```

This will return :

```
UK|England|Bedfordshire |Bedford    |ShopA
UK|England|Hertfordshire|Stevenage  |ShopB
```

To get `ShopsX`, a category without shops, you need to change the last join to a left join *and* check for a null ParentID for `country`:

```
select country.name,region.name,county.name,town.name,shop.name
from shops country
inner join shops region on region.ParentID=country.id
inner join shops county on county.ParentID=region.id
inner join shops town on town.ParentID=county.id
left join shops shop on shop.parentid=town.id
where country.parentid is null
```

returns

```
UK|England|Bedfordshire |Bedford    |ShopA
UK|England|Hertfordshire|Stevenage  |ShopB
UK|England|Hertfordshire|ShopsX |NULL
```

If you didn't check for `Country.ParentID is null`, each Shop line would try to join with the table again, find no match and *still* return with a NULL:

```
UK      |   England      |  Bedfordshire |  Bedford |   ShopA
England |   Bedfordshire |  Bedford      |  ShopA   |   NULL
UK      |   England      |  Hertfordshire|  Stevenage|  ShopB
England |   Hertfordshire|  Stevenage    |  ShopB   |   NULL
UK      |   England      |  Hertfordshire|  ShopsX  |   NULL
```

This "pivoting" will perform very fast if `ID` and `ParentID` are indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is a mash-up of the my standard recursive cte to build the hierarchy.  (added COC  or chain-of-command)

Then we apply a little xml to parse the COC.  Currently 9 positions, but easy to expand or contract.

```
Declare @YourTable table (id int,Name varchar(50),ParentId  int)
Insert into @YourTable values 
 (1   ,'UK',            NULL)
,(2   ,'England',       1)
,(3   ,'Bedfordshire',  2)
,(4   ,'Bedford',       3)
,(5   ,'ShopA',         4) 
,(6   ,'Hertfordshire', 2)
,(7   ,'Stevenage',     6)
,(8   ,'ShopB',         7)
,(9   ,'ShopsX',        6)

Declare @Nest   varchar(25) = '|-----'  --<<  Optional: Added for readability

;with cteP as (
      Select Seq  = cast(10000+Row_Number() over (Order by Name) as varchar(500))
            ,ID
            ,ParentId 
            ,Lvl=1
            ,Name 
            ,COC  = cast(Name as varchar(max))
      From   @YourTable 
      Where  ParentId is null
      Union  All
      Select Seq  = cast(concat(p.Seq,'.',10000+Row_Number() over (Order by r.Name)) as varchar(500))
            ,r.ID
            ,r.ParentId 
            ,p.Lvl+1
            ,r.Name 
            ,COC  = p.COC+'||'+cast(r.Name as varchar(max))
      From   @YourTable r
      Join   cteP p on r.ParentId  = p.ID)
     ,cteR1 as (Select *,R1=Row_Number() over (Order By Seq) From cteP)
     ,cteR2 as (Select A.ID,R2=Max(B.R1) From cteR1 A Join cteR1 B on (B.Seq like A.Seq+'%') Group By A.Seq,A.ID )
Select C.*
 From cteR1 A
 Join cteR2 B on A.ID=B.ID
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos7 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos8 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos9 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select A.COC as [*] For XML Path('')),'||','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) C
 Where R1=R2
 Order By A.R1
```

**Returns**

[image]

If it helps with the visualization.

When the final select is:

```
Select A.R1  
      ,B.R2
      ,A.ID
      ,A.ParentId 
      ,A.Lvl
      ,Name = Replicate(@Nest,A.Lvl-1) + A.Name
 From cteR1 A
 Join cteR2 B on A.ID=B.ID
 Order by R1
```

The results would be

[image]

Comment: For what cost? Besides, if you needs advanced hierarchy processing, it's better to spend the effort to add a HierarchyID. Even that though may not beat the self-joins in *this* case (0.01658 cost)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos as I mentioned "another option".  There is no doubt that self-join is very efficient.  However, the key here are the Range Keys (R1/R2).  They facilitate non-recursive aggregation and navigation.